# Skype API call always cancelled

Tags: c#, skype

I have small application which calls phone numbers in Skype and allows to record conversations.

But it doesn't work with Skype versions after 7.5. I tried both `Skype4COM` and direct API:

For `Skype4COM` call always gets status `clsCancelled`, `FailureReason` is `cfrMiscError`. Below example code:

```
Skype skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();

if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
{
    skype.Client.Start(true, true);
}

skype.Attach(skype.Protocol, true);

Call call = skype.PlaceCall("+17606604690");
```

For direct API call status is `MISSED`. I'm using following command to start a call `CALL +17606604690`. It is possible to start call with somebody from your contact list by starting IM with him and bringing Skype client in focus, but this approach doesn't work for mobile numbers.

I guess Skype API changed after version 7.5, because I see that other applications still able to place calls. I'm also aware about Skype URLs, but they have big delays and won't let you know if call fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some discussion of this problem [here, with a work‐around](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-API-PlaceCall-is-broken-in-latest-versions/m-p/4215511/highlight/true#M388564):

> I made a shortcut to only call the skypecall part and surprisingly, if i spam it, it starts in. A triple try-catch cycle does the trick, but to make sure, i just applied force retry until its status becomes "ringing"